# ATtiny2313 accidental wrong fuse settings with crystal

Tags: avr, crystal, avrdude

I wanted to add external 12.000 MHz crystal to ATtiny2313.

I connected it (both crystal pins to ground using 0.1μF capacitor) and flashed fuse bits.

```
avrdude -P /dev/parport0 -p t2313 -c bsd -U lfuse:w:0x64:m -U hfuse:w:0xdf:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m
```

After flashing fuse bits, ATtiny2313 didn't start up and avrdude won't read it either.

What should I do?

Comment: 0.1 uf on the crystal pins??? That's 100000 pf - try 10pf...

Comment: those would do fine? http://tinyurl.com/llq7yxw

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I already use parallel mode(bsd programmer)

Comment: "Parallel mode" doesn't mean using a parallel port.

Comment: The fuse settings you have applied are the normal ones (8 MHz internal RC), I don't see how this could lead to a problem. Are you sure the values you have used are the ones you posted?

Comment: i'm very sure, i used online fuse calculator(http://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc)

Comment: @mikroskeem there is no need for using URL shorteners on stackexchange. Comment fields are usually long enough and it is unclear where the URL is pointing to (which is a security concern).

Comment: @alexan_e is correct, in your question are the default fuses and those shouldn't be a problem A. Are you absolutely sure you used those? Which exact programmer are you using? If you are unsure which fuses you set, you may have to revert to high voltage programming, like is done with an Arduino [here](http://www.rickety.us/2010/03/arduino-avr-high-voltage-serial-programmer/) (do check the fuse settings in the software though) or for example with an Atmel AVR Dragon or various other commercial programmers.

Comment: @mikroskeem Did you press the apply button in the calculator after making changes to the clock options, if not the shown value doesn't reflect the selected options (the result of the calculator is not automatically refreshed).

Comment: @mikroskeem just reading thru comments - you didn't seem to acknowledge what Brian Drummond said - if you are using 0.1uF capacitors on the xtal it will not work until they rust thru and hell freezes over.

Comment: @alexan_e ofc i did press apply

Comment: @jippie URL shortener!? and, i'm using BSD Parallel port programmer

Comment: `URL shortener` He means the "tinyurl.com.." link you posted in the second comment. Can you tell us what are the settings you want to apply? As far as I can see the default values are the same as the values you provide [snapshot](http://postimg.org/image/tuxkr5lbp/) while the crystal setting are [snapshot](http://postimg.org/image/fd0dj5u0l/)

Comment: @alexan_e yeah, i frogot :P anyway snapshot link: http://www.upload.ee/image/3876946/Capture2.PNG

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 100nF capacitors on the XTAL lines to ground. Normal range is a couple of pF to maybe 20 or 30 pF. The ones you have fitted are between 5,000 and 10,000 times too big in capacitance: -

10pF = 0.01nF

1nF = 1000pF

100nF = 100,000pF = 0.1uF

Comment: i will try 10pf capacitors...